# ActionMailer test fails in Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, actionmailer

I have a test in notifier_test.rb, where Notifier is my mailer class

```
mail = Notifier.registered_client(client.firstname, client.emailaddress)

assert_match I18n.t('notifier.registered_client.email_body'), mail.body.encoded, 'Email contents should be correct'
```

This test used to pass prior to Rails 3.2.8 but the test now fails with:

```
NotifierTest
      FAIL (0:00:07.963) should create registration email in English
      Email contents should be correct.
      Expected /In\ order\ to\ activate\ your\ company's\ registration\ you\ must\ click\ on\ the\ following\ link:/ 
      to match 
      "\nDear First Name, thanks for registering.\n\nIn order to activate your company\&#x27;s registration you must click on the following link:\n\nhttp://localhost:3000/en/clients/activate?email=english%40email.com&key=7b6e6ed1-ac03-4d95-a0d5-6f2541092dd0\n".
```

The error seems to be arising because the text of my mail contains an apostrophe which `mail.body.encoded` is now returning as `\&#x27;` due to the patch for:

CVE-2012-3464 Potential XSS Vulnerability in Ruby on Rails described in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubyonrails-security/kKGNeMrnmiY/r2yM7xy-G48J

What's the smartest way to either encode the string returned by I18n.t in the same way, or else get the text without the apostrophe from my mail object?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I got to this to work by using

CGI.unescapeHTML(mail.body.encoded)

so that the line

assert_match I18n.t('notifier.registered_client.email_greeting', name: firstname), CGI.unescapeHTML(mail.body.encoded), 'Email greeting should be present'

passed testing

Comment: Was this issue limited to test code or in production emails do you also need to use CGI.unescapeHTML?

Comment: Thanks for your question and sorry I have been slow to respond.
While the action I described above DID resolve the issue the underlying problem turned out to be something different.
I am using a translation file and had not named the translation string for the mail body with _html.
I think I am correct in saying that as a result Rails decided to escape this string and so I therefore had to unescape it to get the test to pass and match the original text in the translation file.